# Unable to install Communda pluggin to eclipse kepler 4.3.1

Tags: eclipse-plugin, camunda, camunda-modeler

ways to produce(**i am trying this** )

> Help-> install new software-> add-> add a repository

here i am only adding the 
**http://camunda.org/release/camunda-eclipse-plugin/update-sites/kepler/archive/2.7.0/**

getting below log file error

> !MESSAGE Unable to connect to repository
>   http://camunda.org/release/camunda-eclipse-plugin/update-sites/kepler/archive/2.7.0/content.xml

I have already tried unchecking "Contact all updated sites during install to find required s/w" button

Comment: Works fine for me. Probably a proxy issue in your setup.

Answer (score 1):

As the camunda eclipse plugin is deprecated i would suggest you the usage of the camunda modeler: https://camunda.org/download/modeler/